# Redirect when page isn't exactly found

Tags: php, html, search, redirect, location

Okay, so I posted here the other day and it was a ton of help so I decided to come back. I have another problem with the same code. I wanted to add another source to it which I used = "$location_url2" I then added a second "$content" to match the code up. the difference between the two sources is "$location_url" returns a blank page if nothing is found, but "$lcation_url2" redirects to index.php if nothing is found, but keeps the extension on the url... The code I'm using:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $search_text = $_POST['search'];
        $location_url = "http://cydia.saurik.com/package/{$search_text}/"; 
        $location_url2 = "http://rpetri.ch/cydia/{$search_text}/";
        $content = @file_get_contents($location_url);
        $content2 = @file_get_contents($location_url2);

        if($content) {
            header("Location: {$location_url}");
        } else if($content2) {
            header("Location: {$location_url2}");
        } else {
            header("Location: suggest.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="search">
    <form method="POST" name="search" action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="search" name="placeholder" placeholder="Search Tweaks..."/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be hard to do, unless you're absolutely sure the two links return nothing when nothing's found. If either of the two locations return something like a 404 your script will interpret the 404 as actual content and redirect there... You might need to look for an alternative way of determining if a site "has content or not"

You could check the header for a 200 like this:

```
$header=get_headers($url,true);
```

and then test $header[0] to have "200" in it... it makes it dodgy code though. If at any time one of the URL's returns any unexpected output with HTTP/1.1 200 OK in the header your script will think it's all ok

There's also a lot of redundancy in your code. Right now $location_url2 is downloaded even if there's content in $location_url, which is only burning resources and makes your scripting slower than needed...

I would go somewhere alongs the lines of this: (keep in mind, you're highly depending on what the url's return):

```
<?

$search_text=filter_input(INPUT_POST,"search",FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);

if($search_text!=""){
    $location_url = "http://cydia.saurik.com/package/{$search_text}/";
    $location_url2 = "http://rpetri.ch/cydia/{$search_text}/";

    $content=@file_header($location_url,true);
    if(strpos($content,"200 OK")!==false) 
        header("Location: {$location_url}");
    else{
        $content=@file_header($location_url2,true);
        if(strpos($content,"200 OK")!==false)
            header("Location: {$location_url2}");
        else
            header("Location: http://www.amazingjokes.com");
    }
}
```